# What is best, a Single-threaded or a multi-threaded server?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have to create a simple client<->server communication to transfer files using C language (Linux).

The server accept connections on the 10000 port, I don't know if is better to create a new thread each request or create a fixed numbers of threads and use asynchronous technique.

```
CASE A:

client --> server --> (new thread) --> process the request

CASE B:

SERVER --> create thread 1 - thread 2 - thread 3

then

client1 --> server --> thread 1
client2 --> server --> thread 2
client3 --> server --> thread 3
client4 --> server --> thread 1
client5 --> server --> thread 2
client6 --> server --> thread 3
```

In this case thread 1 could process many client's requests

My considerations:

**CASE 1:** Is faster but waste a lot of memory

**CASE 2:** Is slower but use a low memory

Am I wrong?

Comment: It should depend on the number of clients and the rate of usage. Usually, fixed number of threads are used. But if you have a lot of performance requirement without upgrading the hardware increase the number of threads. I believe, an optimal performance/memory balance is requires based on the intended usage

Answer (score 7):

If you consider checking architecture of widely used http servers ( nginx, lighttpd, apache ) you'll notice, that ones using fixed thread count ( so called "worker threads", their amount should depend on processsor count on server ) are **a lot** faster then one using large thread pool. However, there are very important moments:

1. "Worker thread" implementation should not be as straightforward as it is tempting, or there will be no real performance gain. Each thread should implement each one pseudo concurrency using state machine, processing multiple requests at time. No blocking operations can be allowed here - for example, the time in thread that is wated to wait for I/O from hard drive to get file contents can be used to parse request for next client. That is pretty difficult code to write, though.
2. Thread-based solution ( with re-usable thread pool, as thread creation IS heavyweight operation ) is optimal when considering performance vs coding time vs code support. If your server is not supposed to handle thousands of requests per second, you'll get ability to code in pretty natural blocking style without risking to fail in performance completely.
3. As you can notice, "worker thread" solutions itself service only statical data, they proxy dynamic script execution to some other programs. As far as I know ( may be wrong ), that is due to complexities with non-blocking processing of request with some unknown dynamic stuff executed in their context. That should not be an issue in your case, anyway, as you speak about simple file transfer.

The reason why limited thread solution is faster on heavy-load systems - thread http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch is pretty costful operation, as it requires saving data from registers and loading new one, as long as some other thread-local data. If you have too many threads compared to process count ( like 1000x more ), a lot of time in your application will be wasted simply switching between threads.

So, short answer to your question is: "No, it has nothing to do with memory usage, choice is all about type of data served, planned request/second count and ability to spend a lot of time on coding".

Answer (score 3):

There's no right answer here. Depends on a lot of things. And you need to choose by yourself.

"CASE 1: Is faster but waste a lot of memory
"CASE 2: Is slower but use a low memory"

Wrong. Depends on a lot of things. Creating threads is not that expensive (it is, but not that much), but if the threads got too many, you'll have a problem.

This depends on the load very much - what is the expected load? If it is, lets say, about 1000 requests per second - you know, if you create 1000 threads each second..... this will be disaster :D

Also - create as many threads, as the CPU will be able to handle, without (much) switching between them. There's a big chance (depends on your program, of course), a single-core CPU to work much, much slower with 10 threads, instead of 1(or 2). This really depends on what will these threads do, too.

I'd choose to create a thread pool and reuse the threads.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov ok. But the point is... if i have a fixed number of threads (example: 10 threads). is better to process "small" part of each request and LOOP to all the requests. Or block those 10 threads..finish the first 10 requests and then continue with the next? i can reuse the thread, i think is better...but 1 thread = 1 request (and then reuse the same thread for other) OR 1 thread = many requests (sending small piece of file each time?)

Comment: @Dail - As I said in my other comment - "I'd definitely choose the first option - "10 request "simultaneously", so 10 x time". It's not necessary to block all 10 threads, just implement(or find implemented) pipe. Create a thread to receive the requests and push them in the queue. Then create other threads, that will simply get requests from the pipe and send them.

Comment: These threads should be able to wait for requests from the pipe blocking (using select - http://linux.die.net/man/2/select ), otherwise there will be a really big load of the CPU.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov I'm not totally convinced.. If I have fixed 10 threads, and 10 users download a .iso file (800 mb) the thread will be block until the download is terminated. SO I think is better to send small piece of file each time. is wrong this consideration?

Comment: Well, it depends, again. This is really subjective. OK, this is important, too - the size of these requests. As we're talking about a large amount of data - yes, than sending smaller pieces will be better, because it's not good to make all other clients to wait like forever. As I said at the beginning, it depends on the load. If you expect small amount of clients, downloading large files - than you can make threads per each request. But if you don't, than just create threads-pool and send smaller pieces of data, to be able to handle all clients, waiting for some data.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov Ok, I can try to send good quantity of KB each "piece" or you think is better to choose a fixed KB?

Comment: @Dail - I'm not sure that it does matter at all. If you send fixed number of bytes and the downloading has stopped for some reason, the fill will still be useless (if it's binary). Depends on the clients, too. I also don't know that does "good quantity of KB each "piece"" means. I think that this would be a good new stackoverflow question, as this is no more related to the number of threads.

Answer (score 3):

My first choice would be to do it single-threaded using select(2). 
If that wasn't good enough performance-wise I'd go with a thread-pool solution.
It will scale better.

There are times where creating one thread per client is perfectly ok. 
I've done that and it worked well for that application, with usually around 100 client up to a maximum of 1000 clients. That was 15 years ago. Today the same application can probably handle 10000 clients due to better hardware. Just be aware that one thread per client doesn't scale very well.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been quite a while since you asked this, but here's my take on your question from a perspective of someone who already wrote a handful of servers in C.

If your server is your own, totally dependent, and non-dependent on others codes, I would **highly** recommend that you do it **single-threaded** with non-blocking sockets and using epoll (Linux), kqueue (BSD) or WSAEventSelect (Windows).

This may require that you split down a code that would have been otherwise "simple" to much smaller chunks, but if scalability is what you're looking after, this will beat any thread-based / select based servers.

There was a great article once called "The C10K Problem" that is focused entirely around the problem of how to handle 10,000 concurrent connections. I actually learned alot myself from it, Here's the link to it: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html .

There is also another great article that focus around scalability called "Scalable Networking" that you can find here: http://bulk.fefe.de/scalable-networking.pdf .

Those two are great reads, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It *really* depends on what your server is doing.

I would recommend that you do the simplest thing possible. This is probably a single-process model, which multiplexes all available connections using, select, poll, libevent or similar.

That is, if you're using TCP.

If you use UDP, it's even easier as the application can do everything with one socket, so it can (possibly) use a blocking socket.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the pool of pre created threads and re-use them when they are done with the current request they're handling.  Creating threads can be expensive, as it mostly involves calls into the kernel.

There is "threadpool" type project [here](http://people.clarkson.edu/~jmatthew/cs644.archive/cs644.fa2001/proj/pthreadsPool/) using pthreads.  Perhaps you can get some ideas from there on how to implement.